# NIC can't detect on MS Hyper-V Virtual Machine

Tags: hyper-v, nic

DELL T610 Broadcom NetXtreme II NIC can't detect on MS Hyper-V Virtual Machine.
How can I do?

Comment: Have you checked device manager, is it showing in there? We need more information.

Comment: I have install windows server 2008 on VM and it can detect NIC as Windows Virtual Network Adpter. Windows Server 2003 can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to install the virtual machine integration components.  Then the drivers for the network adapter will be in your Server 2003 installation.

Comment: installed W2K3 SP2 & Hyper-V Integration Tools on VM
after that W2K3 can detect VMBus as Virtual Network.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to add the NIC as a emulated/legacy network adapter instead of as an synthetic network adapter. Installing the virtual guest services should allow a synthetic adapter to be recognized as well.

Comment: In Hyper-V, "legacy" is "emulated."